# Running VM's on windows

Tags: linux, windows-7, virtual-machine

I have a Win7 Home Premium box and I'd like to run a Linux VM on it. I'm looking for a free solution. In particular I need the VM to accept inbound network connections.

I've used VirtualPC before but IIRC it doesn't fit my network requirements. I took a look at VMWhere Player but I'm not sure it does either and it was asking a lot more questions in the registration form than I want to answer just to try it out.

Does anyone know of a solution that they know to fit my requirements?

(BTW, I can upgrade to ultimate if needed.)

Comment: VMWare Player is nice, just fill in nonsense for the registration (aside from the email).

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, give VirtualBox a try. It's free, can run on Windows 7 and Linux will run on it quite easily. There are a number of methods you can use to set up the network, you should be able to get it to accept network connections quite easily.

http://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Taking a look, now all I need is an ISO to install from (darn slow network connection :).

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with VMWare Server, which is a free-of-charge download.